# expss Package into Markdown PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, expss

I cant seem to get the following code chunk to work in PDF markdown, it only works in HTML. I tried re-installing latex through tinytex, but still nothing is working. Here the following error I get:
**Error: ncol(obj1) is not NULL or ncol(obj2) is not NULL or ncol(obj1) not equal to ncol(obj2)**

This is the code chunk in question, because without this, the document knits. Thank you for any insight you might give.

```
SPSST %>% 
  tab_cells(edu.RC, race.RC, relig.RC, age.RC) %>% #rows
  tab_cols(total(), income.RC) %>% #columns
  tab_weight(popwght) %>% #weights
  tab_stat_rpct() %>% #column percents
  tab_pivot() %>% #make pivot table (think excel)
  set_caption("Cross Tables of Recoded Variables (WEIGHTED)")
```

Comment: @gdemin I'm having the same trouble knitting into PDF.

Comment: @Ben Which expss version do you use? There was incompatibility between huxtable and expss. It should be fixed in the latest release.

Comment: @gdemin I am using 0.10.1

Comment: @Ben Please, try to update to the latest version which is 0.10.6.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to pass the `expss` results to `kable`. Add the following commands to your script and it should render into PDF via Rmarkdown.

```
library(kableExtra)

... 
split_table_to_df() %>%
kable() %>% kable_styling()
```